# Concatenating unknown number of masks

Tags: python, iterator, concatenation, mask

I have an array of boolean values of shape `(height, width, num_of_instances)` (for example `(2448, 2048, 233)`).
I'd like to return a array of shape `(height, width, 1)`, where every value is True if any of the values in the 233 masks at the same position is True.
I don't always know the number of instances and height and width. Currently I am iterating over every pixel:

```
for j in masks.shape[0]:
   for i in masks.shape[1]:
      if any(masks[j, i, :):
          resulting_mask[j, i] = True
```

This is extremly slow as one would expect. So what would be quick and pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
resulting_mask = np.any(masks,axis=2)[:,:,None]
```

Comment: it returns shape ```(height, width)```, would be a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: I missed that you wanted (height,width,1).  Added the reshaping to the suggestion

Comment: I just had a look in the documenation, the option ```keepdim=True``` does the same! Thanks again!